# How to update height of one element with height of a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I update using JS/jQuery the height of an element by class name with the height of their corresponding element inside them?

for example, I have:

`"heightClass", 47` and `"heightSem", 35` . Can I do it using jquery, to make `"heightClass", 35`.

Here is the example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var heightClass = $(this).find('.Example').height();

    console.log('heightClass', heightClass);

    
        var heightSem = $(this).find('sem').height();

    console.log('heightSem', heightSem);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<me class="Example">
<hr>
<sem>Sample work showcases the immense capability of our talented writers. <br> Browse sample documents and use filters to narrow down your</sem>
</me>


<br><br>

<me class="Example">
<hr>
<sem>Sample work showcases the immense capability of our talented writers. <br> </sem>
</me>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by *How can I update with jquery so that I make `"heightClass", 35` and for the second tag `"heightSem", is 16` the `"heightClass"`, should be updated to 16 as well.*? BTW parent elements could not inherit their height from their children and it is vice-versa, so whenever the child `height` changes it won't affect parent `height`.

Comment: @SMAKSS indeed, so how can I force it to affect the parent height using jquery, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqjg5vbw/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).find('.Example').each(function(index){
      var heightSem = $(this).find('sem').height()
      console.log('heightSem'+index, heightSem);
      var heightClass = $(this).height(heightSem);
      console.log('heightClass'+ index, heightClass.height());
 
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<me class="Example">
<hr>
<sem>Sample work showcases the immense capability of our talented writers. <br> Browse sample documents and use filters to narrow down your</sem>
</me>


<br><br>

<me class="Example">
<hr>
<sem>Sample work showcases the immense capability of our talented writers. <br> </sem>
</me>
```